# excel VBA copying to blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to find help with my last part on macro and cannot find working macro set.
My macro have to copy data from A1-C1 (all 3 cells have to be copied in 1 copy data in a row) to another list starting on first blank cells starting from column A5-C5 and available range is from A5-C5 to A300-C300, second range is from D5-F5 to D300-F300 etc.. up to CG5-CJ5 to CG300-CJ300.
Can someone please help me with creating macro for it?
Thank you so much

PS: Im using this( not working bcz this is not for variable cell which i need and dont know how to apply certain data into it)

```
          ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/1/2022")
Range("A2:C300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=1
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/2/2022")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("D5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=1
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/3/2022")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something yourself first, the below code may be useful addition to your macro:

```
dim rownum as integer
rownum = range("A300").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If rownum < 5 Then rownum = 5
cells(rownum, 1).value = range("A1").value
cells(rownum, 2).value = range("B1").value
cells(rownum, 3).value = range("C1").value
```

for the columns, you may want to add something like:

```
dim rownum as integer
dim colnum as integer
colnum = range("CK5").End(xlLeft).Column
rownum = cells(301,colnum).end(xlUp).Row + 1
if rownum < 5 then rownum = 5
cells(rownum, colnum).value = range("A1").value
cells(rownum, colnum + 1).value = range("B1").value
cells(rownum, colnum + 2).value = range("C1").value
```

Comment: on       dim rownum as integer
dim colnum as integer
colnum = range("CK5").End(xlLeft).Column
rownum = cells(301,colnum).end(xlUp).Row + 1.  its showing every line on debugger :(